# I am trying to count the total number of button clicks with two buttons and display that in a text area

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display the total number of button clicks from two buttons in a text area. I'm mostly struggling with the function containing global count. I am a beginnner by the way...

I'm currently using this code:

```
<form name=simpleForm>
<input type="button" name="button1" value="A" onclick="displayText1()">
<br>
<input type="button" name="button2" value="B" onclick="displayText2()">
<input type="button" name="button3" value="Total" 
onclick="displayText3()">
<textarea name="response" rows 2 cols=27> </textarea>
<input type="reset"value="Reset Form">
</form> 

<head>
<title>interactive web page</title>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function displayText1(){
    document.simpleForm.response.value="You clicked button A!";
    }
    function displayText2(){
    document.simpleForm.response.value="You clicked button B!";
    }
</script>
</head>
```

this is the main function I cant get to work

```
function xxx () {
  var count1 = 0;
  count1 = count1+1;
  globalCount = globalCount+1;
  alert("global Count: "+globalCount):
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a _clear problem statement_.  Please read [ask] and [mcve], with a focus on a _clear problem statement_.  What's wrong? What doesn't work? Do you get an error? What is the error?

Comment: is it just me or is the `head` is below the body part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to display the number of clicks for Button A, and Button B "SEPARATELY"?

You could use Javascript + jQuery: (Provided that you have imported jQuery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var buttonAClickCount = 0;
var buttonBClickCount = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buttonA").click(function(){
      buttonAClickCount++;
      $("#textAreaDisplayButtonA").val(buttonAClickCount);
    });
    $("#buttonB").click(function() {
      buttonBClickCount++;
      $("#textAreaDisplayButtonB").val(buttonBClickCount);
    });
});
</script>

...

<button type="button" class="btn" id="buttonA">Button A</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="buttonB">Button B</button>

<textarea id="textAreaDisplayButtonA" rows="2" colspan="30"></textarea>
<textarea id="textAreaDisplayButtonB" rows="2" colspan="30"></textarea>
```

Comment: @tillman Considering that you have said that you are a beginner, I am assuming you have never jQuery before. I am really sorry if you have and think that I am being rude. Anyways, the first `<script type='text/javascript>` should have an added `src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'` so that jQuery can be read. So it should look like this: `<script type='text/javascript src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'>`

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below. You have to set the onclick event on the button you want to show and the globalCount variable must be outside of all functions in your script if you want to always add a value to it.

Hope it helps! :)

```
  <form name=simpleForm>
    <input type="button" name="button1" value="A" onclick="displayText1()">
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="button2" value="B" onclick="displayText2()">
    <input type="button" name="button3" value="Total" 
    onclick="xxx()">
    <textarea name="response" rows 2 cols=27> </textarea>
    <input type="reset"value="Reset Form">
    </form> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var globalCount = 0;
        function xxx () {
        var count1 = 0;
        count1 = count1+1;
        globalCount = globalCount+1;
        alert("global Count: " + globalCount)}
        function displayText1(){
            document.simpleForm.response.value="You clicked button A!";
            }
            function displayText2(){
            document.simpleForm.response.value="You clicked button B!";
            }
        </script>
```